# Difficultly understanding the inclusion exclusion identity because of difficult notation

Tags: calculus, probability

This is the property: $\mathbb{P}(E1\cup E2\cup ...\cup En)= \sum_{i}^{n} \mathbb{P}(E1) - \sum_{i1<i2} \mathbb{P}(Ei1Ei2) + ... + -1^{r+1}\sum_{i1<i2<...<ir} \mathbb{P}(Ei1Ei2...Eir) + -1^{r+1}\sum_{1<2<...<n} \mathbb{P}(E1E2...En) $

While I understand the property, I don’t understand the summation symbol notation. What does the book mean by $\sum_{i1<i2<...<ir}$? Can someone draw out specifically what this sum is so I can understand it? I lost my question privileges due to this question but can someone please let me know what about this question was so bad? I couldn't find the syntax anywhere.

Comment: I’m not sure why it isn’t showing the whole equation it shows up in my edit

Comment: Learn how to write with [latex](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) .

Comment: use `\cup` for $\cup$ and `\sum_{i=1}^{n}` for $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people would write the sum $\sum_{i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r}$ as
$\sum_{1 \leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r \leq n}$
in order to emphasize that all the variables $i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_r$ have to be between $1$ and $n$ inclusive.

The $r$th sum can be rewritten in more basic summation notation as
$$
\sum_{1 \leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r \leq n} \mathbb{P}(E_{i_1}E_{i_2}\cdots E_{i_r})
= \sum_{i_1 = 1}^{n - r + 1}\, \sum_{i_2 = i_1 + 1}^{n - r + 2}\,
   \sum_{i_3 = i_2 + 1}^{n - r + 3} \cdots  \sum_{i_{r-1} = i_{r-2} + 1}^{n - 1}\,
   \sum_{i_r = i_{r-1} + 1}^{n} \mathbb{P}(E_{i_1}E_{i_2}\cdots E_{i_r}).
$$

Each side of the equation ends up with $\binom nr$ individual terms in the sum, one for each possible sequence of $r$ increasing integers where none is less than $1$ or greater than $n.$
Each of those sequences picks out a different subset of $r$ of the events in the set $\{E_1, E_2, \ldots, E_n\}.$

Personally, I find the notation on the left is a lot easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There are $r$ distinct terms, where $i_1, \ldots, i_r$ are chosen from $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ and satisfies $i_1 < i_2 < \ldots, i_r\}$.

For example if $n=4$, $r=3$,

$$(-1)^{r+1} \sum_{i_1 < i_2<i_3}P(E_{i_1}\cap E_{i_2}\cap E_{i_3})=(-1) \left( P(E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3) + P(E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_4)+P(E_1 \cap E_3 \cap E_4)+P(E_2 \cap E_3 \cap E_3)\right)$$

Using this notation avoid listing the same thing multiple times, for example $P(E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3) = P(E_3 \cap E_2 \cap E_1)$ and we don't want to list it twice.